# Generics in Protobuf-net v2 Model

Tags: c#, generics, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

This seems to work:

```
Model.Add(typeof(ScsMessage), true).AddSubType(20, typeof(Request));
Model.Add(typeof(ScsMessage), true).AddSubType(200, typeof(Event));

Model.Add(typeof(Request), true).AddSubType(102, typeof(Message));
Model.Add(typeof(Request), true).AddSubType(103, typeof(Like));
Model.Add(typeof(Request), true).AddSubType(104, typeof(Tag));

Model.Add(typeof(Event), true).AddSubType(202, typeof(UserEvent<Message>));
Model.Add(typeof(Event), true).AddSubType(203, typeof(UserEvent<Like>));
Model.Add(typeof(Event), true).AddSubType(204, typeof(UserEvent<Tag>));
```

Where UserEvent is defined as:

```
public class UserEvent<T> :Event where T:Request
```

The following (attempt at replacing the third paragraph of code above)  does NOT seem to work. It doesn't generate any compile or run-time errors, but the de-serialization of a UserEvent gives funky results.

```
Model.Add(typeof(Event), true).AddSubType(201, typeof(UserEvent<Request>));
```

Is there any way to do this? It would save on boiler-plate code for each time I define a new class.

Thanks

EDIT: Using the following reflection to set things up instead. Putting here in case someone finds it useful.

```
        foreach (Type type in FindAllDerivedTypes<ScsMessage>
                      (Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Request))))
        {
            Model.Add(typeof(ScsMessage), true).AddSubType(counter++, type);
        }

        foreach (Type type in FindAllDerivedTypes<Request>
                       (Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Request))))
        {
            Model.Add(typeof(Request), true).AddSubType(counter++, type);
            Type constructed = typeof(UserEvent<>).MakeGenericType(type);
            Model.Add(typeof(Event), true).AddSubType(counter++, constructed);
        }
```

.

```
       public static List<Type> FindAllDerivedTypes<T>(Assembly assembly)
       {
        var derivedType = typeof(T);
        return assembly
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(t =>
                t != derivedType && t.BaseType == derivedType  &&
                derivedType.IsAssignableFrom(t)
                ).ToList();

        }
```

Comment: Hi Marc. I don't get the correct object type first of all (a UserEvent<Like> for instance comes out as an ScsMessage (which is the base class of Request/Event). And this ScsMessage has the entire payload in serialized form in its first field (which is a string field that should contain a GUID).  I'll add ScsMessage to the question to make this comment clearer.

Comment: k, I'll try to repro this evening (not at a PC right now)

Comment: Cool. No rush as I've settled on a reflection based solution instead for now (see update). Wouldn't be bad if it triggered some error instead of deserializing incorrectly. Thanks for the great library!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, with regards your reflection example, **be careful** - the key (the number) is very important, and you must be able to reliably reproduce this number in the future. I wouldn't want you to add a new sub-type and find all your data fails because the offsets are off by one.

Cannot reproduce a problem ; the following works fine - please let me know what I am missing:

```
using ProtoBuf.Meta;
using System;
class UserEvent<T> :Event where T:Request
{
    public override string ToString()
    { // to show what we are working with
        return "UserEvent-of-" + typeof (T).Name;
    }
}

// infer the : Request here from the ^^^^
class Message : Request{}
class Like : Request { }
class Tag : Request { }

class ScsMessage {}
// infer : ScsMessage here from the 2 AddSubType
class Request : ScsMessage {}
class Event : ScsMessage { }

class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        var Model = TypeModel.Create();
        Model.Add(typeof(ScsMessage), true).AddSubType(20, typeof(Request));
        Model.Add(typeof(ScsMessage), true).AddSubType(200, typeof(Event));

        Model.Add(typeof(Request), true).AddSubType(102, typeof(Message));
        Model.Add(typeof(Request), true).AddSubType(103, typeof(Like));
        Model.Add(typeof(Request), true).AddSubType(104, typeof(Tag));

        Model.Add(typeof(Event), true).AddSubType(202, typeof(UserEvent<Message>));
        Model.Add(typeof(Event), true).AddSubType(203, typeof(UserEvent<Like>));
        Model.Add(typeof(Event), true).AddSubType(204, typeof(UserEvent<Tag>));

        var obj = new UserEvent<Like>();

        var clone = Model.DeepClone(obj);
        Console.WriteLine(obj);
        Console.WriteLine(clone);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point about the keys. At the moment, rapid development is more important as client/server are tightly coupled, but before deployment I will go back to an explicit model. Your example mirror my first one, which works. Can you try replacing 202,203,204 with one line:

Comment: Model.Add(typeof(Event), true).AddSubType(201, typeof(UserEvent<Request>));

Comment: @Harry why would I do that? A `UserEvent<Request>` is not in an inheritance relationship with `UserEvent<Like>`, nor is it co/contra-variant... you need the 202/203/204, because **that is what the type is**. You can of course have the 201/`UserEvent<Request>` ***in addition to*** the 202/203/204, if you might also be sending `UserEvent<Request>`. However, it is not true that `UserEvent<Like> : UserEvent<Request>`

Comment: OK Marc. That's what I was checking. Guess I misunderstood the finer details of how generics work and thought it could be inferred. Thanks for your response.